# GIT Why do I seem to be on two branches at once?

Tags: git

I'm having quite an issue with my repository...

It seems that I'm on several branches at once and I can't figure out why.

Here's a screenshot of what SourceTree shows:
[image: You can see the commit is selected on the left but there's also a disc next to the commit's description]

I never faced such a problem before.

Would you know of to fix that?
I'll provide any information needed to solve this problem...

Comment: what is the output of `git branch` ?

Comment: git branch tells me * master colored in green. So I guess I'm on the right branch.

Comment: It's a UI/UX issue with SourceTree, not a technical issue with git (note: gitk actually handles this MUCH better by bolding the current branch). The issue is that both branches point to the same commit. So SourceTree puts the labels for both branches on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you are on two branches at once, nor does Git allow this as far as I know.  I believe that your `master` (local) branch and your remote tracking branch `origin/master` are up to date with each other.  SourceTree is simply telling you this by showing both branches adjacent to each other.  I am assuming that you are actually on the `master` branch.

You can confirm this by typing `git status` from the Bash.

Comment: git status tells me I'm on master, so I guess you are right. What actually bothers me is the small disc next to my two branches... I never saw that so I think I did something wrong.

Comment: since july 2016 git introduced worktree which enables user to work on multiple branches simultaneously

Answer (score 3):

You are not "on two branches at once". The following just means that your branch `master` is in the same state as remote `origin/master` branch. You should not "fix" that at all. Keep calm and carry on ;)

Also, you may commit something and you will see that your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit. Then you may `reset` it back.